# Sql stored procedure with 1 declare value, 2 update statement and 1 insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these errors in below stored procedure.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. Column name or number of
>   supplied values does not match table definition.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[tbl_TeleCom_UpdateTeleComNo]

    @type varchar(100) ,
    @comNo varchar(100),
    @status bit

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    Declare @b_ComNo varchar(100)
    Set @b_ComNo = (Select * from tbl_TeleCom where Type = @type)

    IF @b_ComNo IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        Insert Into tbl_ComNoHistory 
        Select B_ComNo, B_StartTime, B_EndTime
        from tbl_TeleCom
        where Type = @type 
        Group By B_ComNo, B_StartTime, B_EndTime    
    END

        Update tbl_Balance Set
        Status = 0
        from tbl_Balance
        Join tbl_TeleCom On tbl_TeleCom.CurrentComNo = tbl_Balance.ComNo
        And tbl_TeleCom.Type = @type

        Update tbl_TeleCom Set 
        CurrentComNo = @comNo,
        CurrentTime = GETDATE(),
        B_ComNo = CurrentComNo,
        B_StartTime = CurrentTime,
        B_EndTime = GETDATE()
        where Type =@type

        Update tbl_Balance Set
        Status = @status
        from tbl_Balance
        Join tbl_TeleCom On tbl_TeleCom.CurrentComNo = tbl_Balance.ComNo
        And tbl_TeleCom.Type = @type
END
```

Comment: and whts you prob here?

Comment: I have these errors.
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: I cann't run the this sql procedure.

Comment: You can't select * into a single variable: Set @b_ComNo = (Select * from tbl_TeleCom where Type = @type)

Comment: Thanks. But I have one error!

Comment: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Then you have to specify the columns for your insert statement like that: INSERT INTO <table> (columns) SELECT ...

Comment: I got it bro! Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[tbl_TeleCom_UpdateTeleComNo]

    @type varchar(100) ,
    @comNo varchar(100),
    @status bit

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    Declare @b_ComNo varchar(100)
    SELECT @b_ComNo = ComNo from tbl_TeleCom where Type = @type

    IF @b_ComNo IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        Insert Into tbl_ComNoHistory 
        Select B_ComNo, B_StartTime, B_EndTime
        from tbl_TeleCom
        where Type = @type 
        Group By B_ComNo, B_StartTime, B_EndTime    
    END

        Update tbl_Balance Set
        Status = 0
        from tbl_Balance
        Join tbl_TeleCom On tbl_TeleCom.CurrentComNo = tbl_Balance.ComNo
        And tbl_TeleCom.Type = @type

        Update tbl_TeleCom Set 
        CurrentComNo = @comNo,
        CurrentTime = GETDATE(),
        B_ComNo = CurrentComNo,
        B_StartTime = CurrentTime,
        B_EndTime = GETDATE()
        where Type =@type

        Update tbl_Balance Set
        Status = @status
        from tbl_Balance
        Join tbl_TeleCom On tbl_TeleCom.CurrentComNo = tbl_Balance.ComNo
        And tbl_TeleCom.Type = @type
END
```